# How to get the stall cycles due to branch prediction misses?

Tags: profiling

The question is how to get the stall cycles due to branch prediction misses?

I am using OProfile to collect the data of my program, but I cannot find any events related to  the stall cycles due to branch prediction misses. The CPU I use is Intel i7.